# Как указать размер изображения в pchart

Tags: php

В документации [pchart](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.draw.drawfromjpg.html) для `drawFromJPG` можно изменять только отступ картинки. А можно ли изменить размер передаваемой картинки? К примеру уменьшить или увеличить ее? Или может есть что то лучше чем pchart?

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно не меняя код библиотеки.

https://github.com/dmelo/pChart/blob/37d8a9e775cde2a4befcd5b70375767d2461c0e3/library/pDraw.php#L1238

Значения берутся из размера вставляемой картинки.

Т.е. Заранее надо преобразовать картинки в желаемый размер или править данную функцию.

Похоже что данная библиотека заброшена, я бы советовал искать что то другое.

Comment: не подскажите что можно использовать? У меня просто есть картинка которая собирается из фона (картинка), картинки и текста. Но туда нужно еще наложить и графику.

Comment: Это не мне решать. Какие требования к проекту? Какие знания и навыки у команды? Я уверен, большинство такие вещи сейчас на js делает. Если все равно можно и эту библиотеку под себя поправить.

Comment: Какие еще требования :))) строчу сам как могу. У меня есть баннер на который я накладываю тексты и картинки разные. Но есть большое желание туда добавить и графику с градиентом. Писать что то свое у меня не хватает ума, а готовое мне что то не подходит(или я криворукий). На `pchart` нет возможности добавить картинку и уменьшить ее в размере. В `JPGraph` та же история. Хотел в свой готовый баннер добавить график, но не смогу вывести его через `imagepng`.

Comment: https://d3js.org/ ?

Comment: к сожалению не то, мне нужно получить картинку в формате PNG. JS мне не пойдет :(